# When empty($var) != ((bool) $var === false)?

Tags: php

Are there any differences between empty() falsy-ness test and bool type cast?

empty detects falsy-ness in the following cases:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Are there any other values that are converted to False in a bool type cast?

Comment: what is the question? not understandable

Comment: Do you think that the list from the PHP Docs is wrong?

Comment: Please describe properly what you want or what your real question?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Thanks Bert, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php as @Bert suggested

Deriving from the table on the page:

```
+-----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
|                       |         |                  |                   |
+-----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
| Expression            | empty() | boolean : if($x) | boolean : if(!$x) |
| $x = "";              | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = null;            | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| var $x;               | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x is undefined       | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = array();         | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = array('a', 'b'); | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = false;           | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = true;            | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = 1;               | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = 42;              | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = 0;               | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = -1;              | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = "1";             | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = "0";             | TRUE    | FALSE            | TRUE              |
| $x = "-1";            | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = "php";           | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = "true";          | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
| $x = "false";         | FALSE   | TRUE             | FALSE             |
+-----------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Which suggests that `empty()` and `if(!$x)` are equivalent.